# When I need to use dev_dependency

Tags: flutter-dependencies

If I need any dependency I use them under `dependencies` like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^3.2.0
  http: ^0.12.0+3
  get_it: ^3.1.0
  connectivity: ^0.4.6
  email_validator: ^1.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+8
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+14
```

When I can use packages uder dev_dependencies? I don't know what I have to see in the packages so that I can decide which dependency goes to which category.

```
dev_dependencies:
```

Answer (score 3):

Pub supports two flavors of dependencies: regular dependencies and dev_dependencies. Dev dependencies differ from regular dependencies in that dev_dependencies of packages you depend on are ignored.

For Example:

If you are developing a package, and you want some packages which are only imported for testing purpose and not the actual implementation, then such packages should go under dev_dependencies. When you are importing a package, pub gets every package that your imported package depends on. Since pub ignores dev_dependencies, the packages which were used for testing won't be fetched by pub.

Comment: what do you mean by "testing purpose"? unit testing or close testing/beta testing?

Comment: if I put my all mentioned dependencies to ```dev_devepencies```and no package under ```dependencies```.  what will be the issue?

Comment: Yes, by testing I mean unit testing. As far as I know, if you are developing a Flutter application it won't cause any issues. But when you are developing packages and plugins, you should include such packages in your dev_dependencies.

Comment: According to docs, The rule for deciding between a regular or dev dependency is simple: If the dependency is imported from something in your lib or bin directories, it needs to be a regular dependency. If it’s only imported from test, example, etc. it can and should be a dev dependency.

Comment: For more information, you can visit https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dev-dependencies

Comment: "Yes, by testing I mean unit testing." now read your main answer. "If you are developing a package, and you want some packages which are only imported for testing purposes (unit testing) and not the actual implementation, then such packages should go under dev_dependencies." it's really confusing answer, when you say testing means unit testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205796/discussion-between-m-arslankhan-and-ayush-bherwani).